# Get first day of current week - x

Tags: php, date, datetime, strtotime, mktime

I need to get the first day of the week (Monday), 8 weeks back from today, where 8 is a variable.

What's the best way to do that in PHP?

Comment: so you mean to say, you need to go 8 weeks back and get a date of monday from that particular week ?

Comment: Yes, exactly what I meant.

Comment: The best way is to use [datetime functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.datetime.php) or [DateTime class](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php)

Comment: @B.1988 follow the link and understand the stuff what alex just mentioned .. it will surely help you and make you understand the logic. All the best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$weeks = 8;

// Timestamp for $weeks weeks ago
$time = strtotime("$weeks weeks ago");

// Day of the week for $time (1 - Mon, ...)
$week_day = date('N', $time);

// Number of days from Monday
$diff = $week_day - 1;

// The date of the Monday $weeks weeks ago
echo date('j', $time - ($diff * 24 * 3600));
```

Comment: For my case, this answer is the best one. I only substituted the output date format to 'd/m/Y'. Thank you everyone for very prompt responses!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this way

```
echo date("l M-d-Y", strtotime('monday this week'));
echo date("l M-d-Y", strtotime('sunday this week'));
echo date("l M-d-Y", strtotime('monday last week'));
echo date("l M-d-Y", strtotime('sunday last week'));
echo date("l M-d-Y", strtotime('monday next week'));
echo date("l M-d-Y", strtotime('sunday next week'));
```

You can also search monthwise

```
echo date("l M-d-Y", strtotime('first day of this month'));
echo date("l M-d-Y", strtotime('last day of this month'));
echo date("l M-d-Y", strtotime('first day of last month'));
echo date("l M-d-Y", strtotime('last day of last month'));
echo date("l M-d-Y", strtotime('first day of next month'));
echo date("l M-d-Y", strtotime('last day of next month'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make some math with dates in PHP like:

```
$now = date('F d, Y H:i');
$newdate = date('F d, Y H:i', strtotime($now.' - 8 weeks'));
echo $newdate;
```

In this case it will output a current date minus 8 weeks.

Also to count which day is today you can use:

```
$dw = date( "w", strtotime($newdate));
```

Where `$dw` will be 0 (for Sunday) through 6 (for Saturday) more informations can be found: [PHP: date](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

**Solution**

In your case it would look as follows:

```
<?php
$weeks = 8;

$now = date('F d, Y H:i:s');
$newdate = date('F d, Y H:i:s', strtotime($now.' - '.$weeks.' weeks'));
$new_date_day = date( "w", strtotime($newdate));
$minus = $new_date_day - 1;

if ($minus < 0) { //check if sunday
    $plus = $minus * -1;
    $newdate = date('F d, Y H:i:s', strtotime($newdate.' + '.$plus.' days'));
} else {    
    $newdate = date('F d, Y H:i:s', strtotime($newdate.' - '.$minus.' days'));
}

echo $newdate;
?>
```

Of course you can `echo` what ever style of date you want. F.ex. `F d, Y H:i:s` will output `November 28, 2016 06:18:03`.

Answer (score 0):

It's not really complicated actually, all you got to do is play a little bit with datetimes ;

```php
<?php
$dt = new Datetime(sprintf('%d weeks ago', 8)); // replace 8 with variable, your value, whatever
$day = $dt->format('w');
$dt->modify(sprintf('%d days go', ($day - 1) % 7));
```

your `$dt` should then have the value you seek